# N-tier architecture with WCF and ASP.NET session state problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, n-tier-architecture

I'm developing one of my personal projects and I found some problem.

It's an n-tier architecture:

- Framework.
- WCF Framework service.
- ASP.NET control that connects to the WCF Framework services in the server-side.
- ASP.NET client hosting that control.

WCF service is in ASP.NET compatibility mode.

What's the problem? Each request is in a different session. I found that because stored values for sessions are reseted in each request, as I stated before.

I've two questions then:

1) - Someway obvious but I want a confirmation - Does the fact of calling WCF Framework services in server-side mean that the session is for the server and not per client?

2) Is first question fact the reason of getting a new session after each request?

In the end, I'm about of disabling ASP.NET compatibility mode for that WCF Framework service and develop my own session state management, which isn't a hard task, but I'm not a friend of reinventing wheels.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF's default instantiation mode is Per-Call: the service call objects exist during each client call. When the client call ends WCF calls `IDisposable.Dispose`. Instantiation type can be set like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)] 
class MyWCFService : IMyWCFContract....
```

There are two more instantiation types: Per-Session Services and Shareable Services.

You should use Per-Session for your project, so you can set your WCF service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class MyWCFService : IMyWCFContract....
```

you can find more details on the MSDN
good luck

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like the right solution. I'll check that later in my home (I'm @ work). I mark as the solution for now.